# Jenkinsfile : fastlane command fails

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I am trying to run `fastlane <lane>` command through `Jenkinsfile` but it fails

```
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35m/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35m/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: ▸ [35mfrom /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'[0m
11:46:33  [11:46:33]: [31mExit status of command 'pod install --repo-update --verbose' was 1 instead of 0.
11:46:33      [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
11:46:33      Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
11:46:33  
11:46:33      export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
11:46:33      [0m
11:46:33  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
11:46:33  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
11:46:33    from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.205.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

But same command works if I ssh as jenkins user and run the command in the same dir.

whats I am missing here ?

I am on `osx/10.15`